# How to add parameter in the web API while calling in C#

Tags: c#

I have given below the sample code, I am calling web API but I am struggling to pass the parameter in the console application.

C# code:

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
var responseTask = client.GetAsync("<web api name>");
responseTask.Wait();

HttpRequestMessage rm = new HttpRequestMessage();
var headers = rm.Headers;

client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_id", "1234xv");
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_secret", "7dfdfsd");

if (responseTask.IsCompleted)
{
    var result = responseTask.Result;

    if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
    {
        var messageTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        messageTask.Wait();                    
        Console.WriteLine("Message from Web API:" + messageTask.Result);                  
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
```

Comment: try using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())

Comment: You should be using `await` for the async calls instead of `.Result` or `Wait()`

Comment: You are making the GET call too early, before adding parameters to the HTTP request  headers. Is the web API expecting the params in headers or query string or body ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were making the GET call much early, even before adding the parameters to the HTTP headers. You need to add the params and then call the GetAsync().
See the modified code below,

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_id", "1234xv");
   client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("client_secret", "7dfdfsd");

   var responseTask = client.GetAsync("http://your api url");
   responseTask.Wait();
   if (responseTask.IsCompleted)
   {
      var result = responseTask.Result;
      if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
      {
          var messageTask = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
          messageTask.Wait();
          Console.WriteLine("Message from Web API:" + messageTask.Result);
          Console.ReadLine();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! @Anand Sowmithiran